# data-bind=" compose:{}" vs <!-- ko compose --> <!-- /ko -->

Tags: knockout.js, data-binding, durandal, composition

Im reading over here (document) 
http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Using-Composition.html

and i can find a markable difference on both compositions rather than have an inner container or no.

first one:

```
<div data-bind="compose: {
            view: 'Box',
            model: 'Box',
            activationData: {
                hasStar: true
            }
        }"></div>
```

and

```
<!-- ko compose: ________ --> <!-- /ko -->
```

(and actually it could have something inside)

Also they talk about the require usage.

Anyone with a good difference ? or when should i use each one ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Knockout names the second binding syntax, `<!-- ko ... -->`, a *virtual element*.

Their sole purpose is to allow you to create data-binds without having to alter your markup.

With a virtual binding, you can for example do this:

```
<ul>
  <li class="category">Fruits</li>
  <!-- ko foreach: fruits -->
  <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
  <!-- /ko -->
</ul>
```

Which could render HTML like this:

```
<ul>
  <li class="category">Fruits</li>
  <li>Banana</li>
  <li>Orange</li>
  <li>Mango</li>
</ul>
```

So in short, you use the *virtual element binding* if you don't have a logical semantic HTML element to put the binding in. If there's already some sort of wrapper around your partial view, I'd advice to use the data-bind *attribute*.

Comment: There's some document about this behavior ? or something ?

Comment: There's a section about virtual bindings in the knockout documentation on custom bindings: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-for-virtual-elements.html